# Disable SwipeRefreshLayout when horizintal scroll handled in two-way Recyclerview

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, swiperefreshlayout

I have a RecyclerView with custom LayoutManager, that has two-way scrolling logic. So, I have overrided it's methods:

```
override fun canScrollVertically(): Boolean = true
override fun canScrollHorizontally(): Boolean = true
```

Then i put RecyclerView in custom SwipeRefreshLayout, **to prevent "swipe to refresh" action when user scrolls my list horizontally**:

```
class CustomSwipeToRefresh
@JvmOverloads
constructor(
        context: Context,
        attrs: AttributeSet? = null
) : SwipeRefreshLayout(context, attrs) {

    private val touchSlop: Int = ViewConfiguration.get(context).scaledTouchSlop
    private var startX = 0f
    private var forbidSwipe = false

    override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        when (event.action) {
            ACTION_DOWN -> startX = event.x
            ACTION_MOVE -> {
                if (abs(event.x - startX) > touchSlop || forbidSwipe) {
                    forbidSwipe = true
                    return false
                }
            }
            ACTION_CANCEL, ACTION_UP -> {
                forbidSwipe = false
            }
        }
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event)
    }

}
```

But this solution doesn't work. Tryed this solution (disabling manualy), but it doesn't work too:

```
override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        when (event.action) {
            ACTION_DOWN -> startX = event.x
            ACTION_MOVE -> {
                if (abs(event.x - startX) > touchSlop || forbidSwipe) {
                    forbidSwipe = true
                    isEnabled = false
                    return false
                }
            }
            ACTION_CANCEL, ACTION_UP -> {
                isEnabled = true
                forbidSwipe = false
            }
        }
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event)
    }
```

Anyway, if I write

```
refreshLayout.isEnabled = false
```

in my onViewCreated in Fragment, it became disabled.

Also tryed to disable SwipeRefreshLayout in RecyclerView.OnScrollListener, but it didn't help.
What is wrong in my code, or SwipeRefreshLayout?

Comment: And where do you set that forbidSwipe to your `SwipeRefreshLayout ` ?

Comment: @h4rd4r7c0r3 in ACTION_MOVE:

`if (abs(event.x - startX) > touchSlop || forbidSwipe) {
                    forbidSwipe = true
                    return false
                }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. After several days of googling I found that all magic of showing and moving spinner located in NestedScrollingParent methods. So, I overrided onNestedScroll method and if `forbidSwipe == true` I just ignore super method:

```
class CustomSwipeToRefresh
@JvmOverloads
constructor(
        context: Context,
        attrs: AttributeSet? = null
) : SwipeRefreshLayout(context, attrs) {

    private val touchSlop: Int = ViewConfiguration.get(context).scaledTouchSlop
    private var startX = 0f
    private var startY = 0f
    private var forbidSwipe = false
    private var isStartScrolledByY = false

    override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        when (event.action) {
            ACTION_DOWN -> {
                startX = event.x
                startY = event.y
            }
            ACTION_MOVE -> {
                val isScrolledByX = abs(event.x - startX) > touchSlop
                val isScrolledByY = abs(event.y - startY) > touchSlop
                if (!forbidSwipe && isScrolledByY) {
                    isStartScrolledByY = true
                }
                if ((isScrolledByX || forbidSwipe) && !isStartScrolledByY) {
                    forbidSwipe = true
                    return false
                }
            }
            ACTION_CANCEL, ACTION_UP -> {
                forbidSwipe = false
                isStartScrolledByY = false
            }
        }
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event)
    }

    override fun onNestedScroll(target: View, dxConsumed: Int, dyConsumed: Int, dxUnconsumed: Int, dyUnconsumed: Int) {
        if (forbidSwipe) return
        super.onNestedScroll(target, dxConsumed, dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed, dyUnconsumed)
    }

}
```

Comment: I have added below line of code to disable swiperefreshlayout while scrolling scrollview and working fine along with @Nikita`s code


binding.swipeRefreshLayout.setOnChildScrollUpCallback { parent, child -> binding.scrollView.getScrollY() > 10 }